# How to get the value of column if I knew the value of other column in the same row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I have to retrieve the column data by using the other column data in the same row which I already knew.

Eg. Table

table Name: fixtures

```
fix_id | fix_against
1837 |  Aus Vs. Eng
2942 |  Ind Vs. SA
```

Here I already knew the 'fix_id'.. So, I need to retrieve the 'fix_against' value using the 'fix_id' in the same row.

Suppose, if **fix_id = 1837**, I will retrieve **Aus v.S Eng** (fix_against) value.

Here is what I tried.

```
global $wpdb; $known_value = 1837;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT fix_against FROM fixtures WHERE fix_id = '$known_value'");
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );echo $result;
```

This doesn't apparently work. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `This doesn't apparently work` ... what isn't working?  You should ideally be using prepared statements, but your query looks right to me.

Comment: I am not a SQL expert, but try this DB-API 2.0 commands to retreive data: `SELECT * FROM fixtures
WHERE fix_id=2942;` ....and BTW your `fix_id` is integer type, so why are you using quotes there ? Try this code: `"SELECT * FROM fixtures  WHERE fix_id=$known_value"` The quotes represent string type data only.

Comment: Or mistake is the semicolon after a statement maybe ? Example: `SELECT * FROM fixtures; WHERE fix_id=$known_value;`

Comment: @s3n0 Appreciate your inputs. I did try all those suggestions but still it's not working.. It's returning 'Array'.

Comment: Try https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp and use the `echo` (PHP) for checking your DB API commands. Maybe there is necessary to use your variable as the string (in the API command string). Your `$sql` is not string, but there is a object inserted and that's wrong, I think. So the same thing, which Ygor Yavych pointed out in the next answer. Try using pure `$sql` string only with DB API 2.0 commands to see if it works. Do not forget to use the `echo` command (PHP) or at least the debugging console to find out the cause and check to see if the correct DB API command is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is right. Your problem is here :

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
echo $result;
```

By default, `$wpdb->get_results` returns an array of objects. In your case, something like `$result[0]->fix_against` would work. However, if you only need value of one cell, you're better off using [`$wpdb->get_var`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/)

```
$fix_against = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
echo $fix_against;
```

If you only need one row, you could use [`$wpdb->get_row`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/)

```
$result= $wpdb->get_row($sql);
echo $result->fix_against;
```

You can learn more about `wpdb` class [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)